# Trying to create laravel query to Select then Insert if record not exist, Update if exist in another table

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I have Postgres Query referring to which i am able to create query in laravel syntax for "select and then insert record".
Not able to apply "if exist, update record" in laravel query.

`postgre query`

```
     INSERT INTO product_details (id, name, hash_id )
     SELECT prod.id, d.name, MD5(CONCAT(d.name, LOWER(prod.id)))
     FROM tmpTable tmp
     INNER JOIN detailsTable d USING(name)
     INNER JOIN productsTable prod ON (prod.id = tmp.id)
     ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT product_details_pkey1
     DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

`Laravel Query`

```
  $query = DB::table('tmpTable  AS tmp')
              ->join('detailsTable AS d', 'tmp.name','=', 'd.name')
             ->join('productsTable AS prod', 'prod.id','=','tmp.id')
             ->select('prod.id', 'd.name','MD5(CONCAT(d.name, LOWER(prod.id)))');            

    DB::table('product_details')->insertUsing(['id', 'name', 'hash_id'], $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "updateOrCreate" method which is provided by the laravel [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Comment: I tried using below methods                         "updateOrCreate", "insertOnDuplicateKey" , "InsertOrUpdate"                              DB::table('product_details')->updateOrCreate(['id', 'name', 'hash_id'], $query);    but error occured as                      Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::UpdateOrCreate()   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::InsertOrUpdate()      Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertOnDuplicateKey()